# CSRF token is undefined when using protractor to test an AngularJS page

Tags: angularjs, csrf, protractor

I'm testing a register page where the user submits an email and a password.

It works as it should when I test the page manually. The problem is when `protractor` opens the url the CSRF-token is `undefined`

```
 ptor.get('http://localhost:8000/client#/rmc');
```

In my angular register controller I set the CSRF token for the post like this:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common["X-CSRFToken"] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```

Is there something special about how protractor gets the page or how it initializes the angular app?

(I use Django's default CSRF middleware and the Django test server)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The problem was **not** with protractor/testing.  There where some old leftover cookies  in my browser that angular used when I checked the page manually. The real problem was that I did no longer sent the cookies. Probably a good reason to do end to end testing from the beginning.

Comment: would you mind letting me know how do you handle this in Django? Not this issue specifically but Django and Protractor playing along

Comment: @Antonio Laguna Not sure what you mean with "playing along". To set it up I followed the official [instructions](https://github.com/angular/protractor) and I run protractor together with the standard local django testserver. But you can also run protractor tests against a staging or live site. If your question is about how to work with logged in users: Protractor does not have a special function for this. You have to register a new user or use a previously created one and let protractor fill the login form. (there is no shortcut login-method for this like with the django test-client)